# Calling UIWebView in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to call the two `UIWebViews` which is declared in other views`(AppleViewController & GoogleViewController)` by calling `UIScrollView` in main view controller. ScrollView is displaying but the problem is the `UIWebView` is not loading to scroll view. What is the problem in my code?

**ViewController.h** file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  

    self.scrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 404);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    pageControl = [[[UIPageControl alloc] init] autorelease];
    pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    AppleViewController *apple=[[AppleViewController alloc]init];
    GoogleViewController *google=[[GoogleViewController alloc]init];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:apple.view];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:google.view];

    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}
```

**AppleViewController.h**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 500,750,350)];
    [webview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    NSString *url2=@"http://www.apple.com";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];
    [self.view addSubview:webview2];
    [webview2 setScalesPageToFit:NO];
    webview2.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;

    [[webview2 layer] setCornerRadius:10];
    [webview2 setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [[webview2 layer] setBorderColor:
    [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[webview2 layer] setBorderWidth:2.75];
    [[self view] addSubview:webview2];
    [webview2 release];
}
```

////GoogleViewController.h

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0,750,350)];  

    [[webview layer] setCornerRadius:10];
    [webview setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [[webview layer] setBorderColor:
    [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[webview layer] setBorderWidth:3];
    [[self view] addSubview:webview];
    [webview release];    
    NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url]; 
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    webview.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;
    [webview goBack];
    [webview goForward];
    webview.opaque = YES;
    webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

Comment: why you want to put it in scrollview?,it will by default scroll.

Comment: This is a bad design to put a `UIWebView` which is a subclass of `UIScrollView` onto a `UIScrollView`. You may want to reconsider what you are doing. Besides that I can't think of any reason what so ever to do this.

Comment: Please suggest me a good way of coding as i'm new to ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line's in your code and it will work:

first,create property of your webview inyour .h file

and write this code like this

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:apple.webview2];
[self.scrollView addSubview:google.webview];
```

And in your applevc put your webview code in initWithNibName method rather than viewdidload method
same in second vc.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,640)];
        [webview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        NSString *url2=@"http://www.apple.com";
        NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
        [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];
        [self.view addSubview:webview2];
        [webview2 setScalesPageToFit:NO];
        webview2.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;

        [[webview2 layer] setCornerRadius:10];
        [webview2 setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [[webview2 layer] setBorderColor:
         [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [[webview2 layer] setBorderWidth:2.75];
        [[self view] addSubview:webview2];
    }
    return self;
}
```